# How can I avoid the "Amount too low" message in my wallet for payout from Cloud mining service?

Tags: transaction-fees, cloud-mining, copay

1) I have a Bitcoin-wallet called "Copay" on my IOS-device
2) I have joined the cloud mining-service "Genesis mining". For trying out the service I started with 50 $ from my credit card. 
3) here is a list of payments I received from them and the fees which yielded always the "Amount too low" message

1. 11th July 2017 3,243 bits   fee 0,00044277 BTC
2. 31st July 2017  1,750 bits   fee 0.02086374 BTC
3. 14th August 2017 1,615 bits  fee 0.00224983 BTC

There is another transaction where I went to a bitcoin shop and bought 10 Euro in Bitcoin which gets the "Amount too low" message.

As a newbie I have some questions

1) Is there a possibility to recover any of these funds without paying fees which are high (e.g. the fee from 31st July amounts to around 100 $) ?
2) Would switching to another wallet remedy the situation
3) Is this a general problem of the Bitcoin network that the fees are rising and thus it is not suitable for transactions below 20 $ ?
4) Would there be a possibility to stop "Genesis Mining" from sending me micro transactions but instead accumulating the funds until a reasonable sum is reached ?

Sorry for having so many questions, I would be grateful for any input

Regards

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After doing research... the fees are currently (mid August) that high... low payments in Bitcoin should be avoided.. there is no glitch in the app

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom miner fee setting to lower fees.  The fee categories make no sense.  If you want a payment to be received in a day or two - faster than ACH, you should set the fee to 10 satosi per byte or so.